# Swift 4: How to use Foundation Locale struct if you have enum with name Locale

Tags: swift4.2

So, I have custom enum with name **Locale**:

```
public enum Locale: String {
    case ru
    case uz
}
```

I'm using it for api response json. If I want use Foundation Locale struct then xcode looks to just my local declared enum. 
How to I can use Foundation Locale struct if I have enum with same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Foundation.Locale` to differentiate Foundation Locale and your local enum